# Combine variables into one variable

Tags: php, variables

I want to make function `merge()` that has variable city and function needs to return sentence that is created after merging values from index array.

```
    function merge() {
    $city = array ("Tokyo", "Paris", "Berlin");
    $index="";
    foreach ($city as $value)
    $index = $index. $value. "";
    return ("$index");

    echo merge();
```

Is this correct way  `$index = $index. $city. "";` of combining variables into one variable? Is there another way?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: `implode()` your welcome.

Comment: if you actually want that function to work: http://ideone.com/JZGr51

Answer (score -1):

Simple,

```
function merge() {
   $city = array ("Tokyo", "Paris", "Berlin");
   $index="";
   foreach ($city as $value)
   $index .=  $value.",";
   echo $index;
}
```

Implode,

```
function merge() {
$city = array ("Tokyo", "Paris", "Berlin");    
$index = implode($city,",");
echo $index;
}
```